# Best way to learn data structures

Tags: c, data-structures

I need to learn data structures through C for my school course.What's the best way to do it? I mean through books or writing code?

Thanks

Comment: Both---reading through books and side by side practicing code!

Comment: Can you suggest a good book?

Comment: Learning anything goes through both the phases of reading and doing it prctically...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I am afraid your question is [off-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: if you need to learn for your school course, then why does your teacher not suggest what book you should follow ? i think you need to go back and ask the teacher for guidance!

Comment: Look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), and also the listed external links.

Comment: Oh yes I guess so.More of a general question than a technical help.

Comment: @wedusk101-I personally recommend this book for you---http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Using-Aaron-Tenenbaum/dp/0131997467 ;one may offer other good suggestions!

Comment: I think the StackExchange's Programmers site is the right place of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is bad question so I will give answer, and not a comment.
Of course, you have to write code and to read books together. But, there is another useful way to learn something. Try to write you own blog or book about structures in C. Then you will have to check all possible solutions, all nuances, to format your code perfectly and to explain in details all structures. That will improve your skills dramatically.
Try to find someone with better skills and to ask questions. Maybe, clone someone's project or just read sources from github.
And last, but not the least. Create your own big project. And use all your skill there. For example, write simple engine for arcade game. That will demand some knowledge in math.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.I'll ask more relevant questions next time.Really appreciate your input.

Comment: I would also suggest to *read* existing source code. So study some free software and contribute to it.